# How to find audio of US Supreme Court oral arguments?

Tags: us-supreme-court, court-records

The newer audio (starting with 2010) are available on the Supreme Court's website. Older arguments are available at www.oyez.org. Oyez page shows the written transcript of the oral arguments as well as the audio recording. While this is wonderful for listening to the audio on the computer, the page has no feature to download the audio file.

(I found a page which explained how to access the audio file (mp3) directly. This involved entering the URL for the source file, which follows a certain formula based on the case number and the URL of the Oyez page. Alas I have forgotten how to do this.)

Does anyone know... How can the audio file be accessed to save or copy?
UPDATE: Apparently there is indeed an download feature. Maybe this is a new update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a browser add-on to download the audio instead of playing it.

I tried [Audio Downloader Prime](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/audio-downloader-prime/) in Firefox but I am sure there are many others that would work.  With it installed, you can click the relevant link on the Oyez page under "Media" (e.g. "Oral Argument"), and along with the usual player, you'll see a notification from the add-on in your toolbar.  Click it, and you'll have an option to download the audio as MP3.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just add, I'm the director of Free Law Project, and we host a TON of audio files over on CourtListener.com (including SCOTUS ones).

They're searchable here:

https://www.courtlistener.com/audio/

We also make podcasts if that's your speed:

https://www.courtlistener.com/podcasts/